# How to make API call and pass header to it using Meteor

Tags: javascript, json, api, meteor

I am trying to call one API using Meteor. The sample code given in API guide is as below:

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(userName + password)));
```

I have to use this code in Meteor, but I have not found any solution yet. I was able to call API which has no header using both `GET` and `POST` method. But how to pass above header to that API call? 
I am using `Meteor.http.post` to make an API call. I am using following code by referring above code:

```
 return Meteor.http.post("url",
   { headers: {"Authorization": "Basic"+(new Buffer(username+password, "ascii")).toString("base64")}, 
   params: { name: username} } );
```

But it's not working. 
I also have working PHP code sample to make this API call:

```
$process = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', $additionalHeaders));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payloadName);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($process);
curl_close($process);
```

Can anyone give me any hint about how to do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the code that does the actual call (omitting any sensitive details, of course). It is not clear what type of API you are trying to use (are you trying to use the .Net API with Node?)

Comment: Using meteor `call` method you can pass headers as shown [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call)

Comment: I have tried 'meteor.http.post', it's working without headers. But how to add header in it?

Comment: It seems that you are missing a space after `"Basic"`. If you are getting any errors, please attach them.

Comment: Actually, header code was correct, but I was passing wrong params. That's why above code was not working. After passing right params, it's working now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
callApi: function () {    
return Meteor.http.post("url",
    { headers: {"Authorization": "Basic"+(new Buffer(username+password, "ascii")).toString("base64")}, 
       params: { name: username} } );
}
```

Using above code in server side code, we can pass headers to an API.